# How to set boolean value true/false in to backbone model attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set boolean value to the model attribute as follows :

```
investAdjustCollection.models[i].set({isUploaded:false});
```

this creates problem when i send request to server to take some action on the modes data but i get the following exception at the client level

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and at the server level i get

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/trade/createinvestadjust 400 (Bad Request)
```

if i remove  `investAdjustCollection.models[i].set({isUploaded:false});` than the server call is made without any issue.

so how to set boolean value true/false in to a bakcbone model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First guess is for unknown reasons (validation failed? bug in the server code?), when you send that data, the server throws an exception and instead of responding with a valid JSON response, the response body is an HTML error page with an error message, so when Backbone tries to parse that as JSON, it's invalid. Check your server side logs. Even though they are saying Bad Request, I suspect an exception in the server. However, just to be sure, use the developer tools to examine the headers and body of your PUT request from the browser and make sure the Content-Type is correct and the request body is valid JSON.

Comment: Yes Peter, i have done all the above you suggested. if i remove setting boolean value in model, the request is fine, I get the exception when i set boolean value to model property.

Comment: @Anto: But is there anything showing up in your server error logs? What does the raw response from the server look like?

Comment: Dollars to donuts there's an HTML body in either a request or a response (most likely a response, really), where JSON is expected. If you had followed my suggestions, you would already know exactly where it's happening and thus understand the root cause. This not a bug in backbone. Hear me now and believe me later. You haven't provided enough detailed information in your post for me to state anything more confidently, but my theory is plausible given the information provided so far.

Comment: @PeterLyons, :) +1 for your post,You are right i get this exception at server side , `Could not read JSON: Unrecognized fieldisUploaded` but how do i fix this?

Comment: Talk to your server team or go look at the server code. That looks like whatever framework the server is written in is generating that error. My guess is there's a mismatch between the defined fields for this resource in the server code and what your are sending from backbone. Are you sure "isUploaded" is exactly the right name, case sensitive?

Comment: @PeterLyons i get ` Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "isUploaded" (Class com.hexgen.ro.request.InvestAdjustRO), not marked as ignorable`

Comment: Basically the back end doesn't support the isUploaded field.